# Why does tspan position incorrectly over 200px font size?

Tags: css, svg, font-size, tspan

Inside a [`text`](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/SVG/Element/text) element a [`tspan`](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/SVG/Element/tspan) allows to style specific parts of text.

```css
html, body, svg
{
  width       : 100%;
  height      : 100%;
  margin      : 0;
  background  : black;
}

text
{
  font-size : 100px;
  fill      : white;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <text y='100'>
    A <tspan>test</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

The [`tspan`](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/SVG/Element/tspan) is correctly located after the text.

[image: Standard tspan position]

However, when [`font-size`](https://dev.mozilla.org/CSS/font-size) exceeds `200px` the position starts to behave differently.

[image: Incorrect tspan position]

The content of [`text`](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/SVG/Element/text) gets also affected. If you wish, you can [inspect](https://dev.mozilla.org/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools#the_inspector_dom_explorer_and_css_editor) yourself.

```css
html, body, svg
{
  width       : 100%;
  height      : 100%;
  margin      : 0;
  background  : black;
}

text
{
  font-size : 250px;
  fill      : white
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <text y='200'>
    A <tspan>test</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

The bigger font, the bigger the difference. Here is the result of [`font-size`](https://dev.mozilla.org/CSS/font-size) at `400px`.

[image: Incorrect tspan position with bigger font]

<sub>[Relative units](https://dev.mozilla.org/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#relative_length_units) (`em` and `%`) have been tested.</sub>
<sub>Other [`text`-related elements](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/SVG/Tutorial/Texts#other_text-related_elements) (`a`) have also been tested.</sub>

Comment: No `viewbox` on the SVG?

Comment: @Paulie_D, there is **no need** for the [`viewBox`](https://dev.mozilla.org/SVG/Attribute/viewBox "MDN Web Docs") attribute. It doesn't solve this issue. It is only a question of responsiveness. The code should be simple as possible.

Comment: I see no difference, is this issue specific to Chrome? Or is it because I'm using a Mac at the moment. At any rate it's not universal.

Comment: It turns out it appears **only** on [Firefox](https://mozilla.org/firefox/). On all editions. (Thank you for the idea to try out on different browsers @RobertLongson.)

Comment: I'm using Firefox and I don't think I'm seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: Tested on two different devices running [Firefox](https://mozilla.org/firefox/ "Mozilla") *89.0.2* and [Firefox Developer Edition](https://mozilla.org/firefox/developer/ "Mozilla") *91b6*. Operating system Windows 10. I filed this as a [bug in BugZilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1722241 "Mozilla BugZilla"). Thank you for help!

Comment: So presumably this is a Windows only bug. Have you tried disabling webrender?

Comment: Yes, I have. It is still the same.